# Updating Privacy Information

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

I'm getting ready to release a new version of my app that has completely eliminated all Google Firebase services and I would like to update my app's information accordingly Now no user data is collected at all, but when I originally submitted the app I disclosed what information was being collected in order to use Firebase services.  I've searched all over the Google Play Console and I cannot find any place to change this information about my app. Is it possible or will I need to submit a new app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are two places you need to modify:

1. from `Google Play Console` chose the app then > `App Content` > `Data Safety`

[image]
this is a new thing in Google Play Console

2. from `Google Play Console` chose the app then > `App Content` > `Privacy Policy`

You should update your privacy policy to reflect that you are not collecting any data any more